# Homomorphism from fundamental group to first homology with coefficients?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be some nice topological space. Let $q\colon \pi_1X \to H_1(X; \mathbb{Z})$ be the morphism which sends a class $[f\colon S^1\to X]\in \pi_1X$ to the class $[f\colon S^1\to X] \in H_1(X; \mathbb{Z})$ where we view $S^1$ as a $1$-simplex with its ends attached. This is the morphism Hatcher uses to prove that $H_1(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is the isomorphic to the abelianisation of $\pi_1X$.

My question may be vague but does the fundamental group $\pi_1X$ still admit the same homomorphism $q\colon \pi_1X \to H_1(X; R)$ to the first homology group $H_1(X;R)$ with coefficients some ring $R$ as in the integral case? I think it should. What do we need to be cautious of when we do the same construction? What unusual things could happen? I am particularly interested in the case when $R = \mathbb{Q, R, C}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If _2 is the standard 2-simplex, then it is **not** homeomorphic to the circle.

Comment: Oops I have fixed it @DanAsimov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because there is a homomoprhism $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)\to H_1(X,R)$ induced by $\mathbb Z\to R$. Moreover, since $H_1(X,R)$ is a $R$-module, by adjunction there is an induced homomorphism $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)\otimes R\to H_1(X,R)$. By the [universal coefficient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem) this is an isomorphism.

In particular, this implies $H_1(X,R)$ is generated (as an $R$-module) by the image of $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks!